# AngularJS - Share ngModel with nested directives and transcluded directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**I am trying to create 3 directives:**

```js
.directive('dirOne', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            this.add = function (tag) {
                tag && $scope.tags.push(tag);
            };
        },
        template: '<div><p>Bucket from directive: {{tags}}</p><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
})
.directive('dirTwo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: '^dirOne',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, dirOne) {
            scope.add = function (tag) {
                dirOne.add(tag);
            };
        },
        template: '<div>'+
            '    <input type="text" ng-model="query" datum="sugestions" dir-three>' +
            '    <button ng-click="add(query)">add</button>' +
            '</div>'
    };
})
.directive('dirThree', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var itemsTemplate = '<span class="sugestions"><span ng-repeat="item in datum|filter:query">{{item.name||item}}</span></span>';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            datum: '=',
            query: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var parent;
            element.wrap('<span>');
            parent = element.parent();
            parent.append(angular.element($compile(itemsTemplate)(scope)));
        }
    };
}])
```

In the *dirTwo* and *dirThree*, I have an input `<input type="text" ng-model="query" datum="sugestions" dir-three>` with *ngModel*, this input needs to access and modify the content of ngModel, so that the scope is not isolated.

http://jsfiddle.net/joaoneto/hbABU/3/

### Update

I Updated version, fix some mistakes I had committed, the content that was being transcluded in dirTwo, should not have the "ADD" function, and belongs to dirTree, hope it helps someone and apologize for peopl take to update this entry... see in http://jsfiddle.net/hbABU/4/

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to do this? I'm with a similar problem myself...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hbABU/4/